# Why is one of my MCU (Bluepill) digital pins broken/not working?

Tags: microcontroller, motor-controller, pinout, back-emf

Sorry for the noob question.

I'm working on an ESC circuit, first I want to work on a very simple ESC circuit without Back-EMF detection like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAaknXe_JSk&ab_channel=Electronoobs

Initially I used 5v from the battery (stepped down using a buck converter) on each collector and it worked. The MCU gets a different supply and not from the battery (I use a 5V USB charger for a cellphone that is connected to STLINKv2 and shares ground with the battery)

Then I increased the voltage to around 9V - 10V suddenly the BLDC motor couldn't rotate and just vibrated. I then checked all pins and pin A10 was broken (couldn't output HIGH/LOW). However, I checked all transistors (I'm using BD139) nothing is damaged.

I don't understand why pin A10 is broken (and only one pin).
Is it damaged because of the BackEMF current from the motor that passes through the Emitter and then to the Base?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably broken because you haven't used current limiter resistors when feeding each base and you've overstressed the IO port on your STM32.

You also need to drive the high-side transistors which much more respect; you cannot drive them like emitter followers because the maximum voltage on each output will be the IO voltage from the STM32 minus about 0.7 volts so, if the STM32 is powered from 3.3 volts, the output voltage cannot be higher than about 2.6 volts.

This is naturally what happens when you use emitter followers in output stages. You should consider using a proper driver for your load and there are plenty to choose from and personally, I'd use MOSFETs because, they have a reverse protection diode built into the silicon whereas, for a BJT you would need to add them to the circuit.